# How come JTables aren't showing additions to them?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I am adding objects from one JTable to another, and I can see through debugging that in the CustomTableModel the objects are being added to the list of objects. Only the first object I add shows up in the new JTable.

So I can add many objects to the TableModel, but only the first one is showing up in the JTable.

here's my add method:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        // TODO add your handling code here:
       if(physPackageModel != null){
        int h = secRowSeat2.getSelectedRow();
        Physical_Package pp = PpackageList.get(h);
           if(physPackageModel2 != null){
                 physPackageModel2.addRow(pp);
                 physPackageModel.removeRow(h);

           }
           else{

                    physPackageModel2 = new tableModel2();
                    physPackageModel2.addRow(pp);
                    physPackageModel.removeRow(h);



           }
        secRowSeat1.setModel(physPackageModel2);
        }
       else{
          int h = secRowSeat2.getSelectedRow();
          EventSeat es = eventSeatList.get(h);

        if(eventSeatModel2 != null){
                eventSeatModel2.addRow(es);
                eventSeatModel.removeRow(h);
        }else{

                eventSeatModel2 = new EventTableModel2();
                eventSeatModel2.addRow(es);
                eventSeatModel.removeRow(h);
           }
        secRowSeat1.setModel(eventSeatModel2);
        secRowSeat2.setModel(eventSeatModel);
        repaint();
       }

    }
```

Let me know if you want to see my custom table model's.....

add and remove methods from customTableModel:

```
public void addRow(Physical_Package rowData)
    {
        insertRow(getRowCount(), rowData);
    }

    public void insertRow(int row, Physical_Package rowData)
    {
        modelData.add(row-1, rowData);
        fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
                this.fireTableDataChanged();
    }
    public void removeRow(int row)
    {
        modelData.remove(row);
        fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void insertRow(int row, Physical_Package rowData)     
{
         modelData.add(row-1, rowData);
         fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
         this.fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

So much for copying the code from the working TableModel I gave you yesterday. That is not the code I gave you.

1. I did not use fireTableDataChanged
2. I did not use "row - 1" in the add(...) method. Of course the fireTableRowsInserted(...) method won't work if you add a row at postion 0, and then tell the table updated you inserted row 1, The table will attempt to repaint row 1.

I don't see why you need any check for the existence of a table model. You should always create and display a table with a table model, even if the table contains no rows.

Comment: for 2. I had to add "-1" to row because I was getting this error `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:367)`

Comment: I also removed the `fireTableDataChanged()` shortly after posting this question, it was just a test. Why do you think I'm getting the out of bounds error? If I sent you my custom table model could you take a look?

Comment: Hey I got the tableModels working without using row-1. I just changed how i was getting row and now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should let table listeners know abut the changes see for example calls fireTableRowsInserted() or fireTableRowsDeleted() in AbstractTableModel

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your code correctly, you're setting a new model each time you move an item.
You should keep the model and call the corresponding fireXxx() methods when adding/removing items.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, i posted my add and remove methods in my customTableModel. is that sufficient or should I do something else?

Comment: Provided that the rest of the custom TableModel is implemented correctly (I assume it extends AbstractTableModel) this should work. The line `this.fireTableDataChanged();` in `insertRow(...)` might be unnecessary, since `fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);` should cause the table to redraw the inserted rows and below.

Comment: ok, it's not working for some reason. I have no clue why... It's like the changes aren't transferring over to the gui models... any other ideas?

Comment: How are you setting the model for the JTable? You need to make sure that the table is registered as a listener to the TableModelEvents fired. The default `setModel()` should be sufficient. Could you debug and check whether AbstractTableModel's `listenerList` contains the JTable?

Comment: I'll do that and get back to you

Comment: @Thomas debugged and found that there aren't any listeners, so that is the problem.. I'm going to try to fix it but let me know if you have any tips besides the `setModel()` method.

Comment: @Thomas actually there are listeners, I just didn't debug far enough. I'm going to work on this some more tomorrow but thanks for the help!